# div position problem in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento

i have a div that drops down using jquery when a user mouses over a link. The css for the div is here:

```
.mask-layer {
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    top: 54px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.slidedown {
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background: url(../images/bg_shopping_bag_span.png); background-repeat:repeat-y;
    color: white;
}
```

Html is simply the slidedown div inside the mask-layer div. For some reason i can't post any angle brackers here to show you.

And finally the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.slidedown').hide(); 
    jQuery('a.top-link-cart').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.slidedown').stop(true, true).animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        }, 600, function() {});
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.slidedown').mouseout(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('.slidedown').stop(true, true).animate({
                    height: '0px'
                }, 600, function() {});
            }, 200 );
        });
    });
});
```

The drop down works well in internet explorer and firefox. However in chrome, the slide down div appears in the wrong position on the page. It appears outside of all other divs on the page at the edge of the screen. Is there a way to fix this? I should mention when i disable the jquery so the div is not hidden and not animated, it is in the correct position even in chrome. So perhaps this is jquery issue? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How about a repro link? Either a live page, or something like http://jsfiddle.net will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you remove the `float: right` from the `.mask-layer`?

If so, try putting `clear: both` in `.slidedown`

Comment: Removing float:right and adding clear:both is an improvement. Now the div slides down but on the far left of the page (within the parent div like it should) which is good. How should i position .mask-layer if i can't use float:right? Perhaps using absolute position in the mask div? It needs to drop down on the far right of the parent div. :)

Comment: I think will have to use absolute position, right:0px, then top:100px to get it to right place. I prefer not to use absolute position but it is relative to the parent div and not the browser window so should be fine i guess.